# Jekyll built-in Sass support media queries generation

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

Trying to figure out how can I use media queries with Sass in Jekyll. For the moment it doesn't work for me.

version: Jekyll 3.8.3

styles.sass

```css
.nav-gallery li
@media (min-width: 768px)
 border-bottom: none
 display: inline-block
 border: 1px solid white

@media (min-width: 768px)
.nav-gallery li
 border-bottom: none
 display: inline-block
 border: 1px solid white

@media (min-width: 768px)
 .nav-gallery li
 border-bottom: none
 display: inline-block
 border: 1px solid white
```

Compiled CSS form:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  border-bottom: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white; }
  
.nav-gallery li {
  border-bottom: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  border-bottom: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white; }
```

Comment: And what's your expected output ?

Comment: anderssonola, @media (min-width: 768px){
.nav-gallery li{
 border-bottom: none
 display: inline-block
 border: 1px solid white}} in css generated styles.css file after jekyll will work with my styles.sass file. I can make it through .scss file clearly, but with sass generation there some rules that i can't fugure out - how make media query working generation to .css

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation seems inconsistent. `Sass` will do that to you (unlike `scss` which cares more about curly braces`{}`).

**Try this**

```
.nav-gallery li
  @media (min-width: 768px)
    border-bottom: none
    display: inline-block
    border: 1px solid white

@media (min-width: 768px)
  .nav-gallery li
    border-bottom: none
    display: inline-block
    border: 1px solid white

@media (min-width: 768px)
  .nav-gallery li
    border-bottom: none
    display: inline-block
    border: 1px solid white
```

**Compiled CSS** View [CodePen](https://codepen.io/whosdustin/pen/xaQYKo)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-gallery li {
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-gallery li {
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-gallery li {
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
}
```

Comment: WhosDustin, thank you, tried your version too, all this three options are compiling by jekyll to not-working .css file like i pasted in post before where there no one css rule that will be workable. Seems to be that is jekyll fault, didn't found anything in it's docs.

Comment: How are you importing your sass files and under what directory? Are `*.sass` files in a `_sass` folder then importing into a `css/main.sass`? The reason I ask is that I use Sass and Jekyll and it works properly. You've peaked my curiosity.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Vm6lgGkcD8GL1A - server runs without any mistakes; _config.yml http://joxi.ru/zANGKbQFB0ekkr, styles.css http://joxi.ru/Dr8jGDoi45w8E2; index.sass http://joxi.ru/D2PGal6Fp80PKm.jpg; index.sass imported by 2-layouts_dir.sass by '@import "index"' and than by styles.sass by '@import "2-layouts/2-layouts_dir.sass"' http://joxi.ru/a2XE1L7i1Wq8qA and http://joxi.ru/Dr8jGDoi45wXZ2